# If statement for when an array has no value (Javascript + HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement, getelementbyid

I have an input box storing various texts into an array and it is displaying on another page, but I want the page to say "No Events" when there is no value in the array

here is the javascript that appends the array to the page

```
function getEvents(){

//get the localstorage from the new event page
events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));

for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
{

    if (events === "undefined" || null || "") {
        document.getElementById("none").innerHTML = "No events";        
    } else {
    // title output
    var title = document.createElement("h1"); //creates h1 element
    var titleText = document.createTextNode(events[i].name); //assigns title 
text
    title.appendChild(titleText); //appends text to h1
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(title); //appends to the 
page

    // date output
    var date = document.createElement("p"); //creates p element
    var dateText = document.createTextNode(events[i].date);  //assigns date 
text
    date.appendChild(dateText); //appends text to p
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(date); //appends to the page
    }
}
}
```

And here is the html on the event loader page

```
<body onload="getEvents()">

    <!-- Title -->
    <center>
        <h1>My Events</h1>
    </center>

    <p id="none"></p>
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If there's nothing in the `events` array, then your `for` loop won't run at all. I think that's what's going on here.

Comment: Basically you should loop in the else part of the loop.

Comment: if(events === "undefined" || null || ""){document.getElementById("none").innerHTML = "No events";}else{for(){}}

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the array so you should test on the array elements not the array itself. Your for loop won't even run if there is no array. So the if that runs tests on the array itself under the scope of the loop has basically no sense.

You can proceed this way just before going beneath the loop:

```
 if (events.length == 0)
 document.getElementById("none").innerHTML = "No events";
```

Answer (score 0):

- Take your if statement out of the for loop
- Use proper syntax for the OR clauses
- properly test for undefined
- Also test for length == 0

```
if (toString.call(events) == "undefined" || events.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("none").innerHTML = "No events";        
} else {
    for(){/*...*/}
}
```